# 3x3 LED grid using NPN transistors to switch (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, led, multiplexer

I am trying to design a basic project to multiplex a 3x3 LED grid in a common anode arrangement. In order to avoid sinking (sourcing?) too much current from the digital I/O pins of the Arduino I would like to uses NPN transistors as a low-side switch for each column.

I understand the case where I use a transistor to switch a single LED with the anode connected to Vs. However, I am having difficulty in designing the circuit for the multiplexed approach.

As my circuit stands I can't understand how to to wire it to source current from Vs and using I/O to control the flow.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To source from Vs or the positive supply (I'm assuming 5V), you could connect it to the GPIO, where a logic High would be the V+ of the microcontroller,  or you could connect it to PNP transistors. The PNP base would then be connected to GPIO instead, like the npn transistors are.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your answer fully. If I connected 5V to the I/O rows will this not always set them high and thus I wont be able to address and control the LED rows? Thanks

Comment: @catslovejazz, exactly, which is why you either connect the "row" to a GPIO directly, or through a PNP type transistor, both of which you can control, like you do the NPN on the low side.

Comment: So I would have a set of NPN to control the columns and a set of PNP to control the rows? This way I will only sink/source a small amount of current from the IO pins and the LEDs will be driven by the Vs/transistors

Comment: Yes. See http://cdn.instructables.com/FNB/1C5O/ICN7G649/FNB1C5OICN7G649.MEDIUM.jpg that said, if you are scanning them at one led at a time, you don't need either row or column transistors. A 3x3 matrix at 20mA would be easy to do directly.

Comment: Fantastic, the only modification I would need is a resistor to limit the current in each column.